# How do I generate and display Django querysets from the results of another queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

For example, let's say I have the following models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Person(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to list all groups, and for each group list the people in the group.

Group A: Person1, Person2, Person3
Group B: Person4, Person5, Person6

I get stuck at Group.objects.all(), which will only return a queryset containing the Group objects that I can cycle through in the template. I don't know how to cycle through the people in each group though. Help?

```
groups = Group.objects.all()

{% for g in groups %}
    g.group_name:
   << Need an inner loop here to cycle through the people in each group? >>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`{% for p in g.person_set.all %}`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: Same issue as the other suggested answer - this causes a database hit for every person. Ideally, I'd only be hitting the database num_groups + 1 times.

Comment: @dopster: I hate to disappoint you, but Django's ORM (and most other ORMs as well) just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin `regroup` tag:

Template:

```
{% regroup people by group as people_by_group %}
{% for group in people_by_group %}
    {{ group.grouper.group_name }}
    {% for person in group.list %}
        {{ person }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Context:

```
{'people': Person.objects.all().select_related('group').order_by('group')}
```

This won't list empty groups, but you can build a similar strucutre in your own view, for example:

```
groups = list(Group.objects.all())
groups_map = dict((g.pk, g) for g in groups)
for g in groups:
    g.person_cache = []
for person in Person.objects.all():
    if person.group_id is not None:
        groups_map[person.group_id].person_cache.append(person)
del groups_map
# ``groups`` now contains a list suitable for your template
```

This way you make only two queries. Using a related manager in a loop will produce `number_of_groups+1` queries.

Comment: The regroup method looks like it is working, but it is hitting the database for every single person. So if I have 4 groups and 24 people, it is running 24 queries...thoughts on why?

Comment: No, it hits the database exactly once and you can check that in: ``django.db.connection.queries``. The result is cached when regroup starts iterating over the queryset (it iterates over it only once anyway, so that doesn't matter).

Comment: django-debug-toolbar shows it hitting the database once for every person...maybe I'm not implementing correctly, though I basically followed your answer to the dot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually query for the people instead of the group.

```
people = Person.objects.select_related().order_by('group')
{% for person in people %}
  {% ifchanged person.group %}
    {{ person.group }}
  {% endifchanged %}
  {{ person }}
{% endfor %}
```

This does one query for all people and their related groups, ordered by group.  The ifchanged in the template recognizes when you've moved on to a new group and prints it out.

Hope that helps.