# Dictionary with arrays in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have dictionary with arrays inside:

```
dicarr = {'category': ['post1','post2', 'e.g.'], 'category2': ['post1','post2']}
```

Array is filled in one cycle:

```
dicarr = {}
for category in Categories.objects.all():
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
    dicarr[category] = [post for post in category_posts ]
```

How can i get access to array from django template? I tried:

```
{% for arrdic in dicarr %}
    {{ arrdic.name }}
        {% for i in arrdic.posts %}
            {{ i.name }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a foreign key pointing to Category on your Post, you don't even need to do it this complicated. All you need to is pass this to the template:

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
```

Then you can iterate like this in the template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.name }}
    {% for post in categories.post_set.all %}
        {{ post.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can do this with any foreign key relationships. Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for respond. This works, and you pointed me to gaps in knowledge of django. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Following your original code, your template should be (also see [`for` tag docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)):

```
{% for category, posts in dicarr.items %}
    {{ category.name }}
        {% for post in posts %}
            {{ post.name }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this isn't the best way to do this, because your view will produce number of queries equal to the number of categories. See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502304/how-do-i-generate-and-display-django-querysets-from-the-results-of-another-querys/4502594#4502594) for a more efficient solutions.